# Scan a perspective image in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, image-processing, scikit-image

I am trying to prepare several images of music sheets taken from different perspectives so that I can do OMR.

I have tried transforming and rotating them but it did not help, I think I need to adjust the images' perspective

[image]

I tried:

```py
def rotate_image(mat, angle):
    height, width = mat.shape[:2] # image shape has 3 dimensions
    image_center = (width/2, height/2) # getRotationMatrix2D needs coordinates in reverse order (width, height) compared to shape

    rotation_mat = cv2.getRotationMatrix2D(image_center, angle, 1.)

    # rotation calculates the cos and sin, taking absolutes of those.
    abs_cos = abs(rotation_mat[0,0])
    abs_sin = abs(rotation_mat[0,1])

    # find the new width and height bounds
    bound_w = int(height * abs_sin + width * abs_cos)
    bound_h = int(height * abs_cos + width * abs_sin)

    # subtract old image center (bringing image back to origo) and adding the new image center coordinates
    rotation_mat[0, 2] += bound_w/2 - image_center[0]
    rotation_mat[1, 2] += bound_h/2 - image_center[1]

    # rotate image with the new bounds and translated rotation matrix
    rotated_mat = cv2.warpAffine(mat, rotation_mat, (bound_w, bound_h), borderValue=[255,255,255,0])
    return rotated_mat

# the first call
def our_rotate(RGBImage):
    angle = getAngle(RGBImage)
    rot = rotate_image(RGBImage,angle)
    return rot
```

Comment: "I try so many ways to fix the perspective of this image" , show what you've tried [ask]

Comment: I will keep editing the post by writing every algorithm I tried

Comment: using opencv's homography transformations should handle this very well if you can either mark or detect the four corners. I'll post a more detailed response later as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

The idea of homography is that given a set of corresponding points we can calculate the matrix required to warp the first set of points onto the second. If we pick out the corners of the sheet music and tell them to warp to a rectangle, then the homography matrix we get back will perform exactly that. By applying that warp to all of the points we can rectify the image.
[image]

[image]

How good the results are will depend on how flat the page was to begin with, how much lens distortion there is (you can use opencv to undistort with some checkboard calibration), and how accurately you can select the corners.

Here's the code:

```py
import cv2
import math
import numpy as np

# corner clicks
corners = []; # assuming clockwise from top-left: [top-left, top-right, bottom-right, bottom-left]
def clicky(event, x, y, flags, param):
    # get globals
    global corners;

    # check for mouse click
    if event == cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONUP:
        if len(corners) < 4:
            corners.append((x,y));

# returns 2d distance
def dist2D(one, two):
    dx = one[0] - two[0];
    dy = one[1] - two[1];
    return math.sqrt(dx*dx + dy*dy);


# load image
img = cv2.imread("sheet.png");

# make a set window
cv2.namedWindow("Image")
cv2.setMouseCallback("Image", clicky)

# loop
done = False;
while not done or len(corners) < 4:
    # make a copy
    copy = img.copy();

    # draw corners
    for corner in corners:
        copy = cv2.circle(copy, corner, 4, (0,0,255), -1);

    # show
    cv2.imshow("Image", copy);
    key = cv2.waitKey(1);

    # check keys
    done = key == ord('q');

# destination points (a rectangle)
margin = 100;
half = int(margin / 2);
height = int(dist2D(corners[0], corners[3]));
width = int(dist2D(corners[0], corners[1]));
rect = [];
rect.append([half,half]);
rect.append([half+width,half]);
rect.append([half+width,half+height]);
rect.append([half,half+height]);

# get the homography matrix
corners = np.array(corners);
rect = np.array(rect);
hmat, ret = cv2.findHomography(corners, rect);

# warp image
warped = cv2.warpPerspective(img, hmat, (width+margin, height+margin));

# show
cv2.imshow("Warped", warped);
cv2.imwrite("marked.png", copy);
cv2.imwrite("warped.png", warped);
cv2.waitKey(0);
```

Comment: thanks very much but my TA in the college told me that he doesn't want the user to do anything because he is making the test on the project by testing them in his docker environment that does not allow us to make any user interactives if you can help me make the computer detect the 4 corners by it self for any image look like these image

Comment: if all of the pictures have a mostly white background you can detect the corners by scanning for black pixels and looking for the four pixels with the most extreme (farthest left, right, up, down) positions.

Comment: actually, that seems like a really fragile strategy. That'd probably break really easily.